# Getting nested object under path is not of nested type in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am getting this error when trying to query nested fields,
this question seems repeating but with little changes, while setting mappings of fields I didn't specify nested but created nested mapping. now when I am trying to query do Neptune full-text search query using gremlin it is working but when I am trying to do a native query it is giving this error :

```
failed to create a query: [nested] nested object under path [predicates] is not of nested type
```

Elasticsearch index mapping

```
{
  "amazon_neptune" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "aggregateId" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "document_type" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "entity_id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "entity_type" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "predicates" : {
          "properties" : {
            "group_name" : {
              "properties" : {
                "value" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "analyzer" : "autocomplete_analyzer",
                  "search_analyzer" : "standard"
                }
              }
            },
            "question" : {
              "properties" : {
                "value" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "analyzer" : "questions_auto_complete_analyzer",
                  "search_analyzer" : "standard"
                }
              }
            },
            "suggestion" : {
              "properties" : {
                "value" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "analyzer" : "autocomplete_analyzer",
                  "search_analyzer" : "standard"
                }
              }
            },
            "type" : {
              "properties" : {
                "value" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "user_name" : {
              "properties" : {
                "value" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "analyzer" : "autocomplete_analyzer",
                  "search_analyzer" : "standard"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

gremlin query which is working

```
g.withSideEffect('Neptune#fts.endpoint',ES Endpoint).withSideEffect('Neptune#fts.queryType', 'match').V().has('suggestion','Neptune#fts life').limit(5).valueMap().toList()
```

Elasticsearch query giving error:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "entity_type": "suggestions"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "document_type": "vertex"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "predicates",
                        "query": {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "predicates.suggestion",
                                "query": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "predicates.suggestion.value": "life"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't specify nested but created nested mapping

That's the issue. If you don't specify `"type": "nested"` explicitly, then `predicates` won't be of type `nested` but of type `object` instead, and your query won't work as you can see.

You need to explicitly define `predicates` as `nested` in your mapping, there's no other way.

**UPDATE**

Your native query should look like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "entity_type": "suggestions"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "document_type": "vertex"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "predicates.suggestion.value": "life"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Val I already tried this, working fine. But how Amazon Neptune gremlin is able to do the same if the native query does not allow that. How can an external tool using the same service is working fine?

Comment: gremlin is not doing a nested query for sure, or it would error out as well. it's doing a normal query and the result is probably not what you want

Comment: But gremlin is returning the expected result, is there any other way I can query something like this?

Comment: then if gremlin that is doing a non-nested query returns the correct results, why do you want to include nested in your native query? i.e. your native query is not equivalent to the one gremlin is making

Comment: I don't know actually how gremlin queries under the hood but the way Neptune store the data is the same as mine.

Comment: then I don't see why nested made its way into your native query

Comment: I am just trying

Comment: Then remove nested and you'll be fine... see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "predicates":{
        "type":"nested",
        "properties":{
          "suggestion":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
              "value":{
                "type":"text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
 {
      "predicates": [
        {
          "suggestion": [
            {
              "value": "life"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Running the same search query, as given in the question:

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64312693",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "predicates": [
            {
              "suggestion": [
                {
                  "value": "life"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I don't see the reason of making `suggestion` nested if it only has a single property.

Comment: I am implementing this for Amazon Neptune FTS, this is how neptune queries on elasticsearch i.e this schema is provided in Neptune docs.